# How can I check if there is a carriage return / new line for every line in a text box?

Tags: c#

```
ID-DIVISION
PROGRAM-ID
WRITER
```

These are the sample strings that I want to check if there is a \r\n for every last character of the strings without using the `Split` command.

Comment: Are these separate strings or one string with `\r\n` causing the line breaks?

Comment: the part that's confusing is "every last character", which is ambiguous. Also, are there multiple lines in any strings? Are you trying to make sure lines are delimited with \r\n and not just \n or \n\r? Are there words in a string and you want to know if every word is followed by \r\n? How else might they be delimited then, spaces, tabs, just \n?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you can clarify your question so we know if your are talking about something other than the straightforward case, it seems that String.EndsWith is the simplest solution to determining if a particular string is at the end of another string.

```
mystring.EndsWith("\r\n");
```

Comment: I always use Environment.NewLine too, but he specifically said \r\n, so I used that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

Try the IndexOf() function of the string object, passing in Environment.NewLine. You can find more details on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx